# Mouseenter and mouseleave firing at the same time

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Mouseenter and mouseleave firing at the same time.
All i wanna do is to hide element when the mouse is on, and show if out

```js
$('#myid').on('mouseenter', function(event) {
  $(this).fadeOut();
});

$('#myid').on('mouseleave', function(event) {
  $(this).stop().fadeIn();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id="myid" >{{property}}</span>
```

Comment: That is because when the element is hidden, the cursor is no longer within its bounds, so it will trigger the `mouseleave` event. You should try playing around with opacity instead, as `fadeOut()` actually sets `display: none`.

Comment: I have wrapped your code in a snippet and have removed `hidden` attribute, so users can test it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Per @Terry's comment, the `fadeOut` event animates the opacity to 0, and then sets the `display` to `none` which hides the element and triggers the `mouseleave` event (since it's no longer hovering something that isn't displayed.

Simply animate the opacity instead of the display (fadeIn, fadeOut)

```js
$('#myid').on('mouseenter', function(event) {
  $(this).animate({'opacity': 0});
});

$('#myid').on('mouseleave', function(event) {
  $(this).animate({'opacity': 1});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id="myid" >{{property}}</span>
```

Comment: And how can i hide this element to not block elements behind this span?

Comment: I have a button under the hidden div, and it aint gonna fire click-event

Comment: `pointer-events: none;` on the span will remove any clicks on the span.

Comment: but is it gonna disable the `mouseenter`/`mouseleave` events?

Comment: Ah, yes, let me come up with something.

Comment: is it really impossible to do such thing?

Answer (score 3):

You can also achieve this effect using only CSS.

```css
#myid {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: 0.4s;
}

#myid:hover {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: 0.4s;
}
```

```html
<span id="myid" >{{property}}</span>
```

Comment: Prefer this answer to the selected one, much cleaner solution

Comment: @JessedeBruijne I'm glad you feel this way. Maybe OP has some case where it is easier for him/her to combine with other actions.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this

```js
$('#myid').on('mouseenter', function(event) {
  $(this).hide();
});

$('#myid').on('mouseleave', function(event) {
  $(this).fadeIn();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id="myid">{{property}}</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:
**add CSS:**

```
#mydiv { -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;  -moz-transition: all 0.3s; -o-transition: all 0.3s; transition: all 0.3s; }
```

add jQuery :

```
jQuery("#mydiv").mouseenter(function(event) {
        jQuery(this).css({
            opacity: '0'
        });
    });
    jQuery("#mydiv").mouseleave(function(event) {
        jQuery(this).css({
            opacity: '1'
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this.

```js
$('#myid').on('mouseenter', function(event) {
  $(this).css('opacity', 0);
});

$('#myid').on('mouseleave', function(event) {
  $(this).css('opacity',1);
});
```

```css
#myid{
  -webkit-transition:0.5s;
  transition:0.5s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id="myid" >{{property}}</span>
```